# Materialize: Make collapsible-header active via js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Trying to add an item to my Materialize accordion dynamically from js and want to make that one active immediately. Tried using this:

```
var accordion = $('#accordion');
accordion.append('<li><div class="collapsible-header active"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div><div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></li>');
```

Element gets added but isn't active. Also tried this after the previous two lines:

```
accordion.children().last().addClass('active');
```

also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collapsible()` to update the accordion after change:

```
var accordion = $('#accordion');
accordion.append('<li><div class="collapsible-header active"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div><div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div></li>');
accordion.collapsible();
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without jquery?